# ¿Como puedo hacer que se quede el color de un botón guardado dependiendo de su estatus en JS ,PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Sigo avanzando con mi proyecto del Hotel. En esta ocasión ya va quedando lo que es las actualizaciones en la base de datos según su estado ocupado o disponible, los detalles que se me han presentado son los siguientes:

1. Al momento de dar clic a un botón por primera vez, se pone en rojo pero no me sale la alerta de que se ha ocupado y si le doy otro clic al mismo botón ahí si arroja la alerta que ya se ha actualizado ya de ahí  todo funciona bien con los demás botones.
2. Al refrescar la página no se me quedan guardado el color ya sea rojo ocupado o verde desocupado, ya que en `javascript` tengo la variable con la clase rentado con el estilo color rojo.

**Update.php**

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    $idHabitacion = (int) $_POST['idHabitacion'] ?? 0;
    $estatus = $_POST['estatus'] ?? '';

    if($idHabitacion > 0 && ($estatus == 'Ocupado' || $estatus == 'Disponible')) {
        $consulta = "UPDATE habitaciones SET estatus = '$estatus' WHERE idHabitacion = '$idHabitacion'";

        if($conexion->query($consulta)) {      
            echo 'La habitación $idHabitacion ahora tiene estado $estatus';
        } else {
            echo 'Hubo un error al actualizar habitación';
        }
    } else {
    echo 'No se recibieron correctamente ID de habitación y estatus';
    }
?>
```

```js
function estatusHabitacion(e) {
  let btn = e.target;
  btn.classList.toggle("rentado");
  let rentado = btn.classList.contains("rentado");
  let habitacion = btn.textContent.replace("H", "");
  console.log(habitacion, rentado);

  $(function() {
    $(".habitacion").click(function() {
      var idHabitacion = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "Update.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          idHabitacion: idHabitacion,
          estatus: rentado ? "Ocupado" : "Disponible",
        },
      }).done(function(result) {
        alert(result);
      });
    });
  });
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let habitacion = document.querySelectorAll(".habitacion");
  habitacion.forEach((habitacion) => {
    habitacion.addEventListener("click", estatusHabitacion);
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: #29bb89;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 6px;
}

.rentado {
  background: #f05945;
}

.disponible {
  background: #29bb89;
}
```

```html
<div id="habitacion" class="contendo">

  <tr>
    <button class="habitacion" value="1">H 1</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="2">H 2</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="3">H 3</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="4">H 4</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="5">H 5</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="6">H 6</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="7">H 7</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="8">H 8</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="9">H 9</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="10">H 10</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="11">H 11</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="12">H 12</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="13">H 13</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="14">H 14</button>
    <button class="habitacion" value="15">H 15</button>
  </tr>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, tu situación no es con el código sino con la lógica... Desde ese punto de vista, te voy a dejar una opción para lograr lo que buscas.

Voy a abordar los dos casos en diferente orden, ya que creo que sería mas fácil de entender.

**Para el caso 2:**

- Necesitas una función `JS` en la que, al cargar la página, envíe una petición a través de `ajax` para consultar el estado de las habitaciones.
- Procesas los datos con `PHP` y retornas el estado.
- En la función `.done` de `ajax` recibes el estado y le asignas de forma dinámica el color y de ser posible, el estado en un atributo adicional, como por ejemplo, `data-estado="Ocupado"` a cada una de las habitaciones de acuerdo al estado recibido desde `PHP`.

**Para el caso 1:**

- Debes capturar el estado actual del atributo `data-estado="Ocupado"` y el número de la habitación en el evento `click`.
- Envías estos dos datos a través de `ajax`.
- Procesas los datos desde `PHP` a tu base de datos.
- Devuelves el nuevo estado a `JS`
- Desde la función `.done` de `ajax`, recibes el nuevo estado, muestras la alerta del cambio de estado, cambias el color y el atributo `data-estado="Disponible"`